# Can I create a single endpoint for authorization and registration?

Tags: python, django, endpoint

I have an interesting problem that I can't cope with, I wrote an api to register a basic django user to which his profile is attached and which does not have anything special at all, now I need this api to perform 2 functions, that is, the user enters his username , mail and password, and the system should check if there is such a user? If there is no such user in the database, then register him otherwise, authorize and return tokens, here is my code:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(default=False, read_only=True)
    refresh_token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    access_token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'is_active', 'refresh_token', 'access_token')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        email = validated_data.pop('email')
        is_active = validated_data.pop('is_active', True)
        username = validated_data.get('username')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, is_active=is_active)
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        return user

    def get_refresh_token(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        return str(refresh)

    def get_access_token(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        return str(refresh.access_token)
```

maybe someone knows how to add an authorization mechanism to it?

Comment: as for me you should do it in `view.py`, not in model